# Bittorrent clients won't open at all, is my ISP throttling them?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, bittorrent, launchd

I noticed that the bittorrent client that I normally use, uTorrent, stopped launching. The icon would pop up on my dock for about 2 seconds, then proceed to disappear and nothing would happen. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, as well as with other bittorrent clients, but nothing seems to work.

I don't know when this started really, and I never changed my ISP, so it doesn't make sense that this is happening.

My application console comes up with the message whenever I try to launch a bittorrent client:

> 24/8/13 6:53:04.102 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503:
>   ([0x0-0x161161].org.m0k.transmission[18785]) Exited: Terminated: 15

I don't know if this problem is actually related to my ISP at all, I'm just making suggestions because I have no idea what is happening.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.7 Lion.

Thank you.

Comment: Your ISP can't stop your Torrent client from starting at all. Have you tried uninstalling it, removing all settings from `~/Library/Application Support/uTorrent` and `~/Library/Preferences/com.bittorrent.uTorrent.plist`, and then re-installing?

Comment: @slhck
Oh okay, that clears up the ISP thing.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, and I just checked those two places you mentioned, neither had any uTorrent or Transmission files/settings.
Very confused here, but thank you for helping!

Comment: If there aren't any settings whatsoever that means you have never used the applications—could that be? Could you try making a new user account on your Mac and see if it works there?

Comment: @slhck Oh sorry I meant there aren't any settings because I securely emptied my trash, deleting all the files related to utorrent and transmission. I did that hoping it was that that made it not work, evidently not... I just tried the new user account thing as well, but it didn't work on there either. Anymore suggestions? Thanks man.